# Python interactive shell with cmd or cmd2 variables?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd2

I am using `cmd` library to design the python interactive tool (shell).
My requirement is to provide variables and store values against variables.
Is it possible in the `cmd` or `cmd2` library?

```
>> get_values **A_VARIABLE 100 B_VARIABLE 200**
```

Expectation is: **`A_VARIABLE`** should store 100 as value and also similarly
      **`B_VARIABLE=200`**. In the code, I should able to access these variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cmd
import os

class Console(cmd.Cmd):

  def do_get_values(self, args):
      args_list = args.split()
      #Empty List
      print "args:", args_list

  def help_get_values(self):
      print '\n'.join(['Get Values',
                      'Usage: get_values 1 3 4 5'])

  def emptyline(self):
    pass

  def do_exit(self, arg):
        """Exits from the console (usage: exit)"""
        return -1

  def do_EOF(self, args):
        """Exit on system end of file character (Usage : CTRL+D)"""
        return self.do_exit(args)

if __name__== "__main__":

    prompt = Console()
    prompt.prompt = "\n>>"
    prompt.cmdloop("Welcome !")
```

My program's output:

```
python dummy_console.py
Welcome !

>>help

Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
EOF  exit  get_values  help


>>get_values 1 2 3
args: ['1', '2', '3']

>>get_values NUM_1 1 NUM_2 2
args: ['NUM_1', '1', 'NUM_2', '2']

>>get_values ANUM 1 BNUM 2
args: ['ANUM', '1', 'BNUM', '2']
```

Note:
    Here I could see all values are taken as arguments.

Comment: What's the `cmd2` library?

Comment: cmd2 is a tool for building interactive command line applications in Python. It is enhanced version of cmd.